# Gridview error when change header name with the only 1 data is visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

From the title above, my code at the first time page_load, there is no problem, it show correctly but after I click button to change language, it is disappear(only show header). I spend about one week to find out but still cannot find what happen.
If the visible data MORE than 1, its working properly.

EDIT:
Forgot to put my page Load method

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NoResult.Visible = false;
        Get_Data();
    }

    protected void Get_Data()
    {

        DBCAD.Service1 myCADDB = new DBCAD.Service1();
        myCADDB.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        string result = "";
        //set web service proxy
        if (!GlobalVariable_CCCNS.filterOrNot)
        {
            //invoke web service method
            result = myCADDB.CallCardStatus_Filter_CCCNSEMBILAN_ALL();
        }
        else
        {
            GlobalVariable_CCCNS.FilterDC = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            //invoke web service method
            if (GlobalVariable_CCCNS.FilterDC == "CCC NS ALL")
            {
                result = myCADDB.CallCardStatus_Filter_CCCNSEMBILAN_ALL();
             }
            else
            {                  
                result = myCADDB.CallCardStatus_Filter(GlobalVariable_CCCNS.FilterDC);
            }
        }

        //read the response data and put in xml document
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(result);
        string mypath = Server.MapPath(@"Data.xml");

        //XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("DBCAD.xml");
        xmlDoc.Save(mypath);

        //set the data set
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds.ReadXml(mypath);

        //Open hidden column
        CallCardStatus.Columns[0].Visible = true;

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            //list out the result to Data Grid
            CallCardStatus.DataSource = ds;
            CallCardStatus.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            NoResult.Visible = true;
        }

        //Clear Unwanted Column
        CallCardStatus.Columns[0].Visible = false;
  }
```

Here is my RowDataBound

```
    string lastRow = "";
    protected void CallCardStatus_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Many item with same id but different status, I just want to visible and get the first row for each id.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var thisRow = e.Row;

            if (thisRow.Cells[0].Text == lastRow)
            {
                e.Row.Visible = false;
            }
            lastRow = thisRow.Cells[0].Text;
        }
    }
```

Here is my RadioButton for Language Malay and English

```
    protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVariable_CCCNS.cultureName = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

        Page.Culture = GlobalVariable_CCCNS.cultureName;
        Page.UICulture = GlobalVariable_CCCNS.cultureName;
        if (GlobalVariable_CCCNS.cultureName == "ms-MY")
        {
            Label2.Visible = false;
            Label2.Text = "Kawalan Status Kad Panggilan";
            Label2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Visible = false;
            Label2.Text = "CallCard Status Monitoring";
            Label2.Visible = true;
        }

        Page_Render();
    }


    protected void Page_Render()
    {
        Page.Culture = GlobalVariable_CCCNS.cultureName;
        Page.UICulture = GlobalVariable_CCCNS.cultureName;
        ALL.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("ALLResource1.Text").ToString();
        Label1.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("Label1Resource1.Text").ToString();
        NoResult.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("NoResultResource1.Text").ToString();

        DBCAD.Service1 myCADDB = new DBCAD.Service1();
        myCADDB.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        string result = "";
        //set web service proxy
        if (!GlobalVariable_CCCNS.filterOrNot)
        {
            //invoke web service method
            result = myCADDB.CallCardStatus_Filter_CCCNSEMBILAN_ALL();
        }
        else
        {
            GlobalVariable_CCCNS.FilterDC = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            //invoke web service method

            if (GlobalVariable_CCCNS.FilterDC == "CCC NS ALL"){
                    result = myCADDB.CallCardStatus_Filter_CCCNSEMBILAN_ALL();
            }else{
                    //invoke web service method
                    result = myCADDB.CallCardStatus_Filter(GlobalVariable_CCCNS.FilterDC);
            }
        }

        //read the response data and put in xml document
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(result);
        string mypath = Server.MapPath(@"Data.xml");

        //XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("DBCAD.xml");
        xmlDoc.Save(mypath);

        //set the data set
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds.ReadXml(mypath);
        // CallCardStatus.DataSource = ds;
        //CallCardStatus.DataBind();

        //Open hidden column
        CallCardStatus.Columns[0].Visible = true;

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            //list out the result to Data Grid
            CallCardStatus.DataSource = ds;
            CallCardStatus.Columns[2].HeaderText = GetLocalResourceObject("ButtonFieldResource1.Text").ToString();
            CallCardStatus.Columns[3].HeaderText = GetLocalResourceObject("BoundFieldResource3.HeaderText").ToString();
            CallCardStatus.Columns[4].HeaderText = GetLocalResourceObject("BoundFieldResource4.HeaderText").ToString();
            CallCardStatus.Columns[5].HeaderText = GetLocalResourceObject("BoundFieldResource5.HeaderText").ToString();
            CallCardStatus.Columns[6].HeaderText = GetLocalResourceObject("BoundFieldResource6.HeaderText").ToString();
            CallCardStatus.Columns[7].HeaderText = GetLocalResourceObject("BoundFieldResource7.HeaderText").ToString();
            CallCardStatus.Columns[8].HeaderText = GetLocalResourceObject("BoundFieldResource8.HeaderText").ToString();
            CallCardStatus.Columns[9].HeaderText = GetLocalResourceObject("BoundFieldResource9.HeaderText").ToString();
            CallCardStatus.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            NoResult.Visible = true;
        }

        //Clear Unwanted Column
        CallCardStatus.Columns[0].Visible = false;
     }
```

Anyone can help?Thanks..Siti..:)

Comment: If my understanding is correct, your `Page_Render` method is used to bind the `GridView` control. Are u calling this method in the `Load` event or only inside the `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: Dear Jupaol, only inside the RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged, do I need to call it in page_load method?

Comment: I just edit the code and put my page load method for your references.

Comment: When controls in ASP.Net _dissepear_ on postbacks, is usually caused to dynamic controls not being re-created on each post, or if you disable the page or control viewstate. In your specific case, I have not found the root cause of the problem, however if u follow my recommendations in my answer, I think u will be able to find the error easier. Oh btw you comment sais: _but after I click button to change language_ but you did not post the code of that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clean up your legacy code a little bit, I recommend you the following: (cleaning your code will help u to spot the error easier)

#### Binding your `GridView`

The best practice to bind a data-bound control is inside the `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!this.IsPostBack)
     {
         // in this method u will bind your GridView
         this.BindGrid();
     }
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, the code inside the `Page_Render` method is used to render your `GridView`, and that code is duplicated in the `Get_Data` method. You could place the code specific to bind your `GridView` inside one single method.

Now you only need to re-bind your `GridView` when its content has changed, for example if you allow your users to edit your `GridView` records. Otherwise, you should not re-bind it. (This is true, as long as your page has `EnableViewState="true"`)

The code to localize your `GridView` columns can be moved to the `GridVew.DataBound` event. Or even better, delegate the logic to localize the view to your markup, to do it, you could create templated columns in your `GridView`.

Example:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" DataSourceID="lds" ID="gv"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text="<%$ Resources: your_resource_file_name_without_extension, your resource_key %>" runat="server" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="a_meaningfull_name" Text='<%# Eval("your_field_name") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

---

#### Set the page language overriding the `Page.InitializeCulture` method:

Note that you only need to set `this.UICulture = culture;` and `this.Culture = culture;` inside this method

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    // you have to call Request.Form, because at this point in the page life cycle, the page viewstate has not been loaded yet
    var culture = this.Request.Form["RadioButtonList1"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(culture))
    {
        // if the values of your list are culture specific (ie. en-US, es-MX, etc) you can uncomment the following line
        // this.Culture = culture;
        this.UICulture = culture;
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
}
```

Using this approach you **do not need the `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged` event.** The code you are placing inside this event won't be necessary.

This code:

```
    if (GlobalVariable_CCCNS.cultureName == "ms-MY")
    {
        Label2.Visible = false;
        Label2.Text = "Kawalan Status Kad Panggilan";
        Label2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Label2.Visible = false;
        Label2.Text = "CallCard Status Monitoring";
        Label2.Visible = true;
    }
```

Can be easily eliminated using markup: (note that you will need to create one resource file for each language you want to use in your application, [to learn more about ASP.Net Globalization click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx))

**Using global resources**

```
<!-- Assuming global resources -->
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text="<%$ Resources: your_resource_file_name_without_extension, your_resource_key %>"  />
```

Your global resource file would look like:

```
  <data name="your_resource_key" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>your text</value>
  </data>
```

**Using local resources**

```
<!-- Assuming local implicit resources -->
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" meta:resourcekey="base_name_of_your_resource_key" Text="default value used to render the control at design time in VS" />
```

In this case, your local resource file would look like:

```
  <data name="base_name_of_your_resource_key.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>your text</value>
  </data>
```

**You do not need to call `Page_Render();` in the `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged` event**

Comment: Thank you. After I set if (!this.IsPostBack) all become OK.I will try to refactor my code based on your suggestion and study more.Your help is much3 appreciated!..:D